# Algorithms for tree structure broken detecting?

Tags: algorithm, tree

I'm currently coding a upgrade system which will do best to avoid more than one upgrade path for a specific higher version, but it may exist due to version branching. So i want to alert to admin when he/she adding new upgrade path.

For example, the existing upgrade version path is as follows:

```
        1.0
        /   \
    1.1     1.2
    /
1.3
```

then, when version 1.4 is added, the new one is like below:

```
        1.0
        /   \
    1.1     1.2
    /       |
1.3         |
    \     /
    1.4
```

What I want at this time is prompting says there exists 2 upgrade paths for v1.0:

a. 1.0 - 1.1 - 1.3 - 1.4

b. 1.0 - 1.2 - 1.4

So what algorithm is suitable for this situation?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to find a cycle in your tree. You can run a DFS (Depth First Search) and mark the leafs. If you come to a leaf that has already been marked, it means that there is an additional path to that leaf(version)